# R - Remove commas from values in a column and place separated values into new rows

Tags: r

I have a column of gene symbols that I have retrieved directly from a database, and some of the rows contain two or more symbols which are comma separated (see example below).

```
SLC6A13
ATP5J2-PTCD1,BUD31,PTCD1
ACOT7
BUD31,PDAP1
TTC26
```

I would like to remove the commas, and place the separated symbols into new rows like so:

```
SLC6A13
ATP5J2-PTCD1
BUD31
PTCD1
ACOT7
BUD3
PDAP1
TTC26
```

I haven't been able to find a straight forward way to do this in R, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use `readLines` and `strsplit` :

```
unlist(strsplit(readLines(textConnection(txt)),','))
 "SLC6A13"      "ATP5J2-PTCD1" "BUD31"        "PTCD1"        "ACOT7"        
 "BUD31"        "PDAP1"        "TTC26"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this vector result to put into a matrix or a data.frame:

```
vec <- scan(text="SLC6A13
 ATP5J2-PTCD1,BUD31,PTCD1
 ACOT7
 BUD31,PDAP1
 TTC26", what=character(), sep=",")
Read 8 items
 vec
[1] "SLC6A13"      "ATP5J2-PTCD1" "BUD31"        "PTCD1"        "ACOT7"        "BUD31"        "PDAP1"       
[8] "TTC26"
```

Perhaps:

```
 as.matrix(vec)
```

(The `scan` function can also read from files. The "text" parameter was only added relatively recently, but it saves typing `file=textConnection("...")`.)